# Instance States and media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, state, instance, media

I'm writing a simple app where activity A has a song playing. When a button is pressed, the media player pauses and activity B opens. When the user goes back to activity A, the mediaplayer is supposed to resume (from where it left off). My question is, what happens when you press the back button on activity B? I know activity B will be killed but is onResume from activity A loaded? Where do I give instruction to resume?

Comment: yes `onResume()` in Activity A will be called. As weill `onStart()` in Activity A

Answer (score 0):

```
onResume  method will be called when a activity is resumed.
```

It seems you have to read [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) before any kind of android programming

Comment: I have mediaplayer.start(); in my onResume function and nothing happens when I hit the back button from activity b.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

My code looks as follows

```
public class Homework extends Activity {

final MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
int media_length;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homework);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homework);
    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
    try {
        afd = getAssets().openFd("rev.mp3");
        mediaplayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        mediaplayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaplayer.start();
    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeworkContinue);
    final Intent openCloser = new Intent(this, EndActivity.class);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaplayer.pause();
            media_length = mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
            startActivity(openCloser);

        }

    });
}

public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onResume();
    mediaplayer.seekTo(media_length);
    mediaplayer.start();
}
```

}

Comment: what is the provblem you are facing?

Comment: Basically when I hit the back button from activity b it loads back into this activity and doesn't play anything.